# How to segment_mean a tensor of [12000,2] to [12,2]?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a tensor of `shape=(?, 2)` and `dtype=float32`. In practise the shape is 12000,2 but this can vary.

`tf.segment_mean` seems to do what I want, to split the tensor into 12 sections of 1000 and average the values, producing a tensor of shape `[12,2]`

Unfortunatly in order to segment_mean, I need to provide segment_id's as a parameter. Since the number of elements is dynamic, the segment_ids must be generated.

I've tried tf.scan to generate the segment_ids, but wasn't able to get it to work. Am I on the right track? Or is there a better way to do this?

To clarify:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    tens1 = tf.constant([
                            [0.1, 1],  
                            [0.2, 0],  
                            [0.3, 0],  
                            [0.4, 0],  
                            [0.5, 0],  
                            [0.6, 1],  
                            [0.7, 0],  
                            [0.7, 0],  
                            [0.8, 0],
                            [0.9, 0],
                            [0.7, 1],
                            [0.8, 0],
                            [0.7, 0],
                            [0.8, 0],
                            [0.7, 0],
                            [0.8, 0],
                            [0.9, 0],
                            [0.7, 1],
                            [0.8, 0],
                            [0.7, 0],
                            [0.8, 0],
                            [0.9, 0],
                            [0.7, 1],
                            [0.8, 0], 
                            [0.97,0] 
                        ]) 

    #seg_ids = tf.scan(lambda a, x: x % 12, tens1) # this line is incorrect
    #would like to dynamically infer the segment_ids from the size of the tensor
    seg_ids = [0,0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11]

    segmean = tf.segment_mean(tens1, seg_ids)
    print segmean.eval()
```

Comment: U always want to split into 12 tensors?.  I understand the input size can be different but will it be multiple of 12 or is it varying sizes? How do you get the segment ids based on just the input length?

Comment: @vijaym Yea the 12 is a configured constant. The input size unfortunately isn't always a multiple of 12. The exact split location doesn't really matter, so if one segment has 999 elements, and the other 1000 that is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input `tensor_1` was a multiple of 12 that you can accomplish the `segment mean` using:

```
tensor_2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reshape(tensor_1, shape=[12, -1, 2]), axis=1)
```

Since its not, we can pad it to the nearest integer multiple of 12 and then apply the above.

```
sec_len = 12
_shape = tf.shape(tensor_1)
pad_size =  tf.cast(tf.ceil(_shape[0] / sec_len)*sec_len, tf.int32) - _shape[0]
zero_padding = tf.zeros((pad_size, _shape[1]), dtype=tensor_1.dtype)
padded = tf.concat([tensor_1, zero_padding], 0)
tensor_2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reshape(padded, shape=[sec_len, -1, 2]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your ids with [`tf.lin_space`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lin_space):

```
NUM_SEGMENTS = 12

tens1 = ...
num_rows = tf.shape(tens1)[0]
seg_ids = tf.lin_space(0, NUM_SEGMENTS, num_rows + 1)[:-1]
# You can actually just use tf.cast but I prefer to explicitly use tf.floor
seg_ids = tf.cast(tf.floor(seg_ids), tf.int32)
segmean = tf.segment_mean(tens1, seg_ids)
```

This has the benefit that if the number of rows is not a multiple of the number of segments the "extra" ones will be distributed in different segments (instead of just added to or removed from the last segment).